# Make Windows Service as a Server C#

Tags: windows, wcf, uwp

I have an existing windows service app in c#. Now I have to create a Universal Windows Platform App (UWP) or windows store app what must communicate with the windows service. The functions of windows service must be the following:

1. Response to the UWP app e.g. when my UWP app sends some command, windows service will response some outputs
2. Windows service must send a command or response to UWP without uwp's request e.g. every 10:00 AM windows service will say hello to UWP

My questions are:

1. Is this possible? Is so can you give some options? I've been searching several times but I can't find an example for me. Although there is WCF which won't fits my needs since it won't  do my needs at number 2 ( Windows service must send a command or response to UWP without uwp's request e.g. every 10:00 AM windows service will say hello to UWP).
2. Can I make windows service like WCF? I believe that windows service is better than WCF in this scenario.

Any response is a  big help for me as C# newbee.

Regards

Comment: What is the nature of the daily "push" message to the UWP app?

Comment: just an example... what i mean on that is Windows service must something like send command to UWP.. is it possible?

Comment: It's possible but it would involve using http. UWP apps are sandboxed from win32 by design. You would have to run an in-proc http listenner inside your UWP app. See http://www.dzhang.com/blog/2012/09/18/a-simple-in-process-http-server-for-windows-8-metro-apps and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559129/creating-a-web-server-in-c-sharp-uwp