# How to read incoming network socket to completion in UWP using C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, uwp

I believe I ran into a solution for .NET but it is not applicable nor am I set to test it out under UWP; please keep in mind I am asking for UWP solution.

```
private async void start()
{
    ... other stuff ...
    listener.ConnectionReceived += conn_received;
    ... other stuff ...
}

private async void conn_received(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    Stream inStream = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inStream);
    string request = reader.ReadLine();
    ... other stuff ...
}
```

I have no problem with writing socket response, but the issue is reading the incoming data entirely, since MSDN did not have a complete example of reading arbitrary amount of unformatted data.

My UWP app is a very simple REST server, it needs to read POST data but Length is not guaranteed to be part of the header nor can I parse it properly.

I can sort of reading entire packet by read(size) with size being a large number, whether that is an acceptable solution itself I have no idea, though the immediate problem of doing that is a performance penalty. So that is not really a usable solution.

When I try out .ReadTimeout or .Length those threw exceptions and not available, so I am not sure how to read incoming network data in its entirety. Read* methods are blind-reads themselves and blocks at the end although I have no way to do the reading.

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand. So you want your UWP to behave as a REST server?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559129/creating-a-web-server-in-c-sharp-uwp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa is helpful?