# Websocket trouble with windows application build with cordova

Tags: windows, cordova, angular

I have a major trouble with my application.

I have an application angular 2. I packaged this app with Cordova. And then with visual studio, I have built a windows application.

In my app I use WebSocket, my app uses WebSockets to send a message to a local server WS. This server is running in local through a windows service.

My problem is that I can't connect my app with the WS server. In the on error event, I don't have anything.

If I build my app on my computer and install it in this same computer it works, but if I install this app in another computer or tablet it doesn't work.

All devices are on windows 10.

Here are my config.xml from my cordova project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget defaultlocale="fr-FR" id="toto" version="1.0.0" windows-packageVersion="1.0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <vs:features />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
  <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" />
  <preference name="WindowsDefaultUriPrefix" value="ms-appx://" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

  <platform name="wp8">
    <splash height="1280" src="res/screens/wp8/SplashScreenImage.png" width="768" />
  </platform>
  <plugin name="cordova-windows-capability-localnetwork" src="https://github.com/dilhan2013/cordova-windows-capability-localnetwork.git" version="0.1.0" />
  <vs:platformSpecificValues>
    <vs:platformSpecificWidget platformName="windows">
    </vs:platformSpecificWidget>
  </vs:platformSpecificValues>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" version="1.0.7" />
</widget>
```

Thank you for your help.
Sorry in advance for my English

Comment: what does your code look like? Welcome to SO, read this [**Asking Help**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this particular situation comes from the fact that the app is trying to reach the Web Socket running on localhost.

Like it is mentioned as an answer to this post : [Cannot connect to localhost in windows store application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833232/cannot-connect-to-localhost-in-windows-store-application), developed windows store app can be isolated from loopback for security reasons.

The solution consists first in finding the installed app PackageFamilyName (this can also be done with the SID from regedit, like in the post mentioned above). For this, run this Power Shell command:

Get-AppxPackage | ? { $_.Name -like '*APP_NAME*' }

APP_NAME can be part of the name you know your app has.

Once the description of the package is displayed, add the app to the NetIsolation exemption list by entering the PackageFamilyName in the following Power Shell command:

CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="PackageFamilyName"

The app should now be part of the exemption list displayed with:

CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -s

And it should be allowed to access the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Check your WS server, does it accept incoming requests from hosts other than localhost?

Comment: The WS server works fine i think.If I just run my application as a website the communication between my website and my WS server works perfectly